# Can I add a button?

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-activity, layout

I am very bad at fixing layouts in android, and I am trying to add a simple button to the top left of the screen. I have already added three buttons in a Relative Layout, and they are just how I want them to be. Now, I want to add one more button, but whenever I try, it messes up the other three buttons:

[image]

Here is the code I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/blurbackground"    
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/levelone"    
        android:text="Level One"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick = "levelone"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"      //Makes it circular
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/leveltwo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/leveltwo"    
        android:text="Level Two (UNLOCKED!)"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick = "leveltwo"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" />    

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/levelthree"    
        android:text="Level Three (UNLOCKED!)"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick = "levelthree"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/leveltwo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/leveltwo"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/leveltwo" />   

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me add another button without moving the rest of my layouts.

EDIT:

I don't have, nor do I want a tool bar! :)

Comment: add custom toolbar in which add button

Comment: What this xml showing the output?

Comment: By Top left, do you mean, an icon in the Action Bar or an icon in the top left in an activity without Action Bar?

Comment: @Anirudh Sorry if it wasn't clear, I don't have an action bar. I just want it in the top left of the screen

Comment: @MustansarSaeed Right now I have it perfect, with three buttons vertical. Now, I want to add another button, without messing up the other three buttons, how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: @Anirudh Feel free to leave an answer if you know what I can do to add a button without messing up my current three buttons! :)

Comment: Its better to use Linear Layout rather than relative and you can easily achieve your goal without messing up the view. Right now in ur current scenario u can make 2 LinearLayout children of main LinearLayout and make them horizontal and then in 2nd linear layout define linearlayout and define your button.

Comment: @UsmanKurd Can you show me how? Thanks so much!

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I have defined rough sketch and Devraj had explained it completely

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:gravity="center"`in RelativeLayout and Add new button like this :
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/layout">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/levelTop"
    android:text="Level Top Left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/levelone"
    android:text="Level One"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:onClick = "levelone"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/levelTop"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/leveltwo"
    android:text="Level Two (UNLOCKED!)"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:onClick = "leveltwo"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/levelone"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/levelthree"
    android:text="Level Three (UNLOCKED!)"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:onClick = "levelthree"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/leveltwo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

Comment: @RuchirBaronia : Remove ``android:gravity="center"`` in RelativeLayout and set position for 4 button again. Try it

Comment: So you changed the gravity into `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`?

Comment: @NullPointerException Yup, if you set ``android:gravity="center"`` for RelativeLayout, another attribute like ``android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`` or ``android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`` will not work. So i remove ``android:gravity="center"`` and set  ``android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"``

Answer (score 1):

[image: here is the code exactly what you want]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="button2"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="button3"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="button4"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nice that it works, But he asked for Relative Layout.

Comment: Nice work devraj its the best approach OP should use to avoid messing the layout.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia yes,It could be horizontal. It will make no change if you are gonna add only one button in this. If you want to add more elements then only you can see the effect.

Comment: @Anirudh, I personally feel that relative layouts are more messy than Linear. you will take same time to fix one Relative layout and ten 5 Linear layout.

Comment: Yes, I myself use Linear Layout. I use Relative Layout when there are too many number of components to handle, easy to specify the positions.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I used gravity to keep the buttons in the center of layout as you know that Linear layout starts putting elements from Top-Left.

Comment: @Anirudh, I avoid to use Relative layout as we have to set margins between elements and it is very difficult to manage them if there are so many elements and we have to display them on different sizes of screen. I personally experienced that and then I switched to leaner layout.

Answer (score 0):

tool_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@mipmap/background_image"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

In Activity include that toolbar as below

```
private Toolbar mToolbar;
 mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
this.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Comment: See his comment, he doesn't have an Action bar, he needs it on top left of screen.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear, but I don't have a tool bar. Thanks so much for your answer, please let me know what to do!

Comment: Is there anyway I can do it without action bar? I do not want an action bar. Also, I will be constantly changing the button's visibility in the java, so do you mind telling me how to do it without action bar? Thanks!

Comment: make action bar xml to layout and include it in xml and make it on tip

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that this is not a button on the toolbar.

If you add a `view` in `RelativeLayout`, it is placed in upper left corner by default. So what you need to do after adding the button is place a bottom margin.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/new_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="value here" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/levelone"    
    android:text="Level One"
    android:layout_below="@id/new_button"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    ..... />
```

The new button should be the first view in your layout.

Btw, your layout is constructed poorly. The idea of using `RelativeLayout` is that the position of your `views` are relative to other `views`. Check out [how to use relative layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) `android:layout_below` etc.

Comment: @NullPointerException Check out my edited answer. I added `android:layout_below="@id/new_button"` which will make `levelone` button place below the new button

Comment: @NullPointerException in your `leveltwo` button, you should also add `android:layout_below="@id/levelone"`

Comment: @NullPointerException also, try to delete the padding in your relative layout.

Comment: Why delete the padding? Thanks!

Comment: Also, why did you make it below rather than above

Comment: Because what you want to do is put the new button at the top of the screen right? That means, level one button should be below the new button.

Comment: Deleting the padding is just a suggestion.

Comment: Also, why did you make it below rather than above

Comment: the `layout_below` in levelone button means, "place level one button below new button"

Answer (score 0):

[image: As you asked, three buttons, Zeroth one at left.]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/blurbackground"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/levelzero"
                android:text="Level zero"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:onClick = "levelzero"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/levelone"
                    android:text="Level One (UNLOCKED!)"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:onClick = "levelone"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                    android:shadowDx="0"
                    android:shadowDy="0"
                    android:shadowRadius="5"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>Layout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/leveltwo"
                    android:text="Level two (UNLOCKED!)"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:onClick = "leveltwo"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                    android:shadowDx="0"
                    android:shadowDy="0"
                    android:shadowRadius="5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/levelthree"
                    android:text="Level two (UNLOCKED!)"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:onClick = "leveltwo"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                    android:shadowDx="0"
                    android:shadowDy="0"
                    android:shadowRadius="5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry for messing up your existing code. Thanks to @Devraj for the code of Linear layout. Edited it to Relative, and added Margins. But this made it work, and I've tested it too. Let me know if you've any doubts. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following xml. `gravity` center needs to be removed. plus new button added

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leftButton"

            android:text="Level Top"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:onClick = "Left top Button"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/levelone"

            android:text="Level One"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:onClick = "levelone"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leveltwo"

            android:text="Level Two (UNLOCKED!)"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:onClick = "leveltwo"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:layout_below="@id/levelone"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/levelthree"

            android:text="Level Three (UNLOCKED!)"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:onClick = "levelthree"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/leveltwo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Removed `gravity`, added new button plus changed the other three buttons from `layout_above` to `lyaout_below` relative to the first button.

Comment: `gravity` will puts all its children to the `center` therefore, the `top left` requirement can't be achieved with this

Comment: its related to good practice that `Level One` button is the first button so it should be added first and then adjust all other buttons according to this button rather than add `Level Three` button from bottom and adjust other buttons

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add that button and make the other buttons lay below it. please go through the following code:
`<Button
            android:id="@+id/newBtn"
            android:text="Left Most Btn"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/levelone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newBtn"
            ..../>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/leveltwo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/levelone"
            ..../>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/levelthree"
            android:layout_below="@+id/leveltwo"
            ..../>`

Answer (score 0):

You can perform well xml funcionality by replaicng Reltive to linear 
A Row sketch would be like this `<LinearLayout
width = "matchParent"
height = "matchParent"
orientation = "vertical">//// thats your main layout
<LinearLayout 
orientation =horizontal>
<Button></LinearLayout> ///1st child layout
<LinearLayout
orientation = vertical>// 2nd child layout 
<Button></Button
<Button><Button>
<Button></Button>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>`

thats a rough skech of what you to achieve right now

Final Vidw will be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="buttonTop"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">




            <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="buttonMain1"
                android:gravity="center"
                />




            <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="buttonMain2"
                android:gravity="center"
                />



            <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="buttonMain3"
                android:gravity="center"

                />




    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not first child is vertical main layout is vertical because it needs 2 partition vertically  and then in 1st child  sub child is placed in horizontal
and in second child children has to b placed in stacking manner so arranged them in vertical orientation

Comment: But you have `orientation =horizontal>` in your second child view in your rough sketch?

Comment: as far you have one child for that there is no ripple effect of using horizontal or vertical but if there is more than one child then it will effect the layout  so for single child either can be used vertical or horizontal

Comment: Hey, I have one question in general about imageButtons. When I specify the image in the `src` attribte, the image is either to small or too big. Should I always specify it in the `background` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to answer you in comment section.

To place an additional button (as you need in your case) you drag a new button and set following three  elements as below :

```
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

If you require to more precise then you may pass values against these elements referencing ID(s) of other/immediate button(s).

Hope it would help you out.

Cheers!

Comment: @Ruchir : To be specific to this question
               android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/levelone"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_alignParentStart="@+id/levelone"

Comment: Answer @Dahn DC reflects same logic what I explained here. Relative layout is ok to implement this design with ease.